# Meteor app sockjs connection closed on Heroku

Tags: javascript, debugging, heroku, meteor, sockjs

I have a Meteor app deployed on Heroku that's suddenly crashing. I'm receiving a mixture of

```
at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/sockjs/info?cb=e2h8vk74gt" host=HOST request_id=89b5ceee-cb5e-48f2-94b9-7c2b8d833c96 fwd=IP dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=22948ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https

at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/sockjs/info?cb=lzf11s02bu" host=HOST request_id=289d7fda-27a2-470d-8ae5-c3e41c0be7d4 fwd=IP dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https 

Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

errors.

It seems like the H13 error means the server stops responding anytime the '/sockjs/inf?cb=xyz' path gets requested. I'm reading that as Meteor's socket programming failing (sockjs). Seems like the 'cb' param goes to a callback after a request is executed. This application does make API requests.

The H12 could then make sense as the server just times out.

I believe the R14 could be related to those errors as memory quota gets exceeded when the failed requests keep piling up.

I've tried to reproduce this issue locally. I sometimes see the H12 sockjs errors if the app fails to authenticate with a web API, but have no way of drilling down into them and seeing what exactly is going on (it just goes into the actual framework code). However, I haven't gotten the server to crash locally. This leads me to believe that it could be something with the Heroku configuration. Any insights?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp8jk.jpg is a screenshot of my localhost sockjs errors in which you could see the xhr reqs failing. However, I don't know how to tell what exactly that request is (whether it's an actual API call or the the router doing something)

On localhost I've also seen 
'WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/sockjs/394/inx5dfkh/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
WebSocketTransport.doCleanup @ sockjs-0.3.4.js:1300' Anybody know how I can go about finding out what exactly is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting these type of errors sporadically.

Not sure of a final root cause, but some insights discovered so far:

1. Meteor times out requests at 30s. Should you have some request that takes longer than that to answer, it will kill it and throw the H12. Indeed the pending request will pile up and you may experience an "overload" on system resources.
2. Using different environments, I've been able to figure that the connection to the Mongo DB (in my case, remote) makes THE difference. The same code in staging and production works well in staging and bad in production. If I point my staging env to the prod DB, I start getting this Meteor delays in answering.
   Checking on the websocket traffic, I've seen that under the production db, subscription / unsubscriptions get a LOT slower. And until those get completed, "the request" (for example, a method call) won't get called in the server.

And that's pretty much where I'm stading now. No idea why the prod DB promotes a slower behavior, being a production cluster vs a free one instance db.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please avoid posting comments as answer. I understand that you need a reputation of 50 to post comments. But still i would recommend to patiently wait till you get the reputation.

Comment: @KarthickRamesh Thanks. Will do. Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: Using an actual prod-ready Mongo Server improve performance?